# Incorrect resolution while external display connected

Tags: display, resolution, displayport

I have an Dell external display which has the best resolution @1440*900.

My laptop is 2015 13 inch rBMP MX840. The problem is that when I connected this external display into the Mac, it cannot show correct resolution, it only shows some general old 4:3 ratio resolution such as 1280*1024 etc.
[image]

I tried to use a utility called `Display Menu` but I still cannot see the optimised resolution. Here I post one screenshot of all resolution shown in that tool.

[image]

Any idea to solve that issue? The correct resolution can be shown when I use my old MBP which comes with a non-retina display. By the way, I am not using Apple official Thunderbolt-VGA converter.

Comment: I’ve got a similar problem with an old Belinea SXGA monitor. OS X 10.11 offers only 4:3 resolutions (e.g. 1280 × 960, defaulting to 1024 × 768), when the screen actually has an aspect ratio of 5:4 (1280 × 1024). Your screenshot reassures me that Apple does support its native resolution, but somehow can’t select it.

Comment: Holding `alt` / `opt` / ⌥ while selecting  _Scaled_ did the trick for me.